# Upper bounds of $x^\top ABAx$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, matrix-norms

Given a unit vector $x=[1~~0~~0~\cdots~0]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and positive definite matrices $A, B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

**My question is** How could we find the upper bound of $x^\top ABA x$ in terms of $x^\top B x$ and a function of $A$, that is
$$x^\top ABA x\leq f(A)x^\top Bx,$$
where $f(A)$ could be any function related to $A$, e.g., the norm of $A$.

Comment: Do you assume $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric matrices?

Comment: @Michael $A, B$ are positive definite, which are thus symmetric by definition.

Answer (score 1):

No such $f$ exists. E.g. suppose $t>0$,
$$
A=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&2},\,B=B(t)=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&t^2} \ \text{ and }\ x=\pmatrix{0\\ t^{-1}}.
$$
Then $x^TBx=1$ and
\begin{aligned}
q(A,B(t),x):=\frac{x^TABAx}{x^TBx}&=x^TABAx=\|B^{1/2}Ax\|_2^2\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&t}\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&2}\pmatrix{0\\ t^{-1}}\right\|_{\,2}^{\,2}\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&t}\pmatrix{t^{-1}\\ 2t^{-1}}\right\|_{\,2}^{\,2}\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{t^{-1}\\ 2}\right\|_{\,2}^{\,2}\\
&=t^{-2}+4.
\end{aligned}
Since $q(A,B(t),x)\to\infty$ as $t\to0^+$, it is not bounded above by any function of $A$.

However, there is an upper bound in terms of both $A$ and $B$. When $x\ne0$, if we put $u=\dfrac{B^{1/2}x}{\|B^{1/2}x\|_2}$, we have
$$
\dfrac{x^TABAx}{x^TBx}=u^TB^{-1/2}ABAB^{-1/2}u\le \rho(B^{-1/2}ABAB^{-1/2})=\|B^{1/2}AB^{-1/2}\|_2^2.
$$